# EditText check if has keyword

Tags: java, android, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I’m making a todo app, and I want to implement a Natural Language detection/processing  system while the user isn’t typing. Mostly like popular todo apps (Todoist, Ticktick, etc). This should support different languages, (I can do the translations).

[image: Natural Language feature looks like this]

I have tried about getting all the words in the EditText (while typing) and then, checking if what was written matches with a keyword stored in strings.xml (so it could handle translations getting one specific language strings.xml file), however, I think this is not the most proper way to do this, it can be bad for the performance, and it is a pain to do because I should write all the synonyms.

My current code looks like this:

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {    
    @Override    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)    
            //Knows that it is a word because it is separated with a space    
            if (s.getCharAt(s.lenght() -1) == ‘ ‘)    
            {    
               String[] words = s.split(“ “);
               for(int i = 0; i < s.words(); i++)    
               {    
                   if (getType(words[i]) == 0)    
                    //Do word stuff
               }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});


    private int TYPE = 0;

    private int getType(String givenword)    
    {     
        String[] words = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.words);    
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)    
        {    
           //As you can see, each item of the string array has their synonym in the item itself, just divided with a “.”    Ex:   house.home    

           String[] synonyms = words[i].split(“.”);    
           for (int ii = 0; ii < synonyms.length(); i++)    
           {
                if (synonyms[ii].equals(givenword)    
                {    
                   return TYPE;
                } 
           }
        }
    }
```

How could I implement this properly? Should I use a Neural Network? And if so, how exactly?

PS: I’d rather not using external libraries

Answer (score 2):

To add autocompletion and translation you have three options .

1- If you are familiar with AI you can train your AI for Natural Language Processing model by using data in any open source data place like Kaggle.

2- Make some logic using database and regular expression for matching user input.

3- Using API this is preferred choice if you aren't familiar with AI Natural Language Processing like Google Cloud Translation API, Google Cloud APIs very good option you can find many useful APIs.